# Artin's Algebra: 'Fibres of the Absolute Value Map'

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm self-studying Algebra, 2nd Ed., by Michael Artin. In section 2.7 he shows this picture:

[image: fibres of a map]

What are these regions?

Clarification:
The inverse image of an element $t$ of $T$ is the subset of $S$ consisting of all elements of $s$ such that $f(s) = t$. It is denoted symbolically as:

$$f^{-1}(t) = \{s \in S | f(s) = t\}$$

These inverse images are defined to be the fibres of the map.

Comment: I found the book on google as a resource from a University: [download](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjA2Oz82djtAhX3FVkFHYjIDtUQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.ustc.edu.cn%2F~liweiyu%2Fdocuments%2FAlgebra%2C%2520Second%2520Edition%2C%2520Michael%2520Artin.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0i5gavx2W-I8UFtaSBO7c1)

Comment: Fibre means preimage of a point, so in this case circles.

Comment: So in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ these are circles and not points?

Comment: Graph $|z|=c$ for $c$ a positive (real) constant.

Comment: Oh! So these fibres have to do with some arbitrarily chosen constants and all complex numbers satisfying $|z| = c$ for $z$ complex, $c$ real.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The fibers of a map $f : X \to Y$ are the different sets $f^{-1}(y), y \in Y$, as $y$ ranges over *every* element of $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *fiber* of a map $f\colon A\to B$ at a point $b\in B$ is the set consisting of all $a\in A$ for which $f(a)=b$. When one speaks of the *fibers of $f$*, this means "all the different sets you can get as fibers of various points $b\in B$." This is a useful concept since the fibers partition $A$: every $a\in A$ is in the fiber of $f$ at $b$ for exactly one $b\in B$.

In this particular case, the fiber of the absolute value function at some $b\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ is the circle in the complex plane centered at $0$ with radius $b$ (I've stipulated $b>0$ since for $b<0$ the fibers are empty). The given diagram shows some of these fibers for some (roughly) arbitrarily chosen values of $b$, which are simply a bunch of concentric circles on the complex plane.

Comment: And of course there’s one fibre that’s a singleton-set.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, although for some reason the diagram is for $|\!\cdot\!|\colon\mathbb C^\times\to\mathbb R^\times$, so that fiber wouldn't appear.